# Trigger to call a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, triggers, ssms

I have a view which extracts specific data. See example below

[image]

I would now like to call a stored procedure whenever a new value is captured by the view when the LocationCode is 'MYS'. Probably a trigger to call a stored procedure? Not sure if this works?

The stored procedure runs based on these columns - ID and ActivityDate, i.e. need to pass them as input  which can be obtained from the data in the view. The Stored Procedure output needs to be stored into a temp table.

```
EXEC dbo.spLocationEvents
@ID = '314AS',
@ActivityDate = '20 Jan 2020 12:00 AM'
```

The data needs to be captured in the temp table every time someone enters a activity for location code 'MYS'.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ActivityEvents_IR] ON [dbo].[ActivityEvents] 
FOR INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
    IF (SELECT LocationCode FROM inserted) LIKE 'MYS' 
    Begin 
        Return 
    END 
    DECLARE @ActivityDate datetime = 'SELECT ' + 'ActivityDate' + ' FROM inserted 
    WHERE LocationCode=''MYS''' 
    DECLARE @ID int = 'SELECT ' + 'id' + ' FROM inserted WHERE LocationCode=''MYS''' 
    INSERT INTO [#TempActivityEvents] 
    EXEC dbo.spLocationEvents @ID = @ID, @Date = @ActivityDate 
END 
GO
```

Comment: You can't trigger on a view access, only on an insert/update to the base table.

Comment: You're asking too much in one question. Check the MS docs on how to build a trigger. Use the Inserted and Deleted tables to work out which rows changed, and what the changed values are, if you must call the SP once per value then iterate through the changes calling the SP. Ideally you write an insert directly into the temp table without calling the SP as that way you could write a set based query instead of having to single row it...

Comment: what do you mean by `whenever a new value is captured by the view` ?

Comment: You probably need to create trigger on the table(s) that is underneath the view. Not on the view

Comment: Ok, The base table has the same information as the view. And I would like to create a trigger to call this stored procedure - 'dbo.spLocationEvents' whenever a value in the base table is inserted with LocationCode as 'MYS'

Comment: in this case you need to create insert trigger for the base table.

Comment: @Squirrel - Tried the following code, but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: `code`   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ActivityEvents_IR] ON [dbo].[ActivityEvents] 
    FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON

 IF (SELECT LocationCode FROM inserted) LIKE 'MYS'
 Begin
  Return
 END

DECLARE @ActivityDate datetime = 'SELECT ' + 'ActivityDate' + ' FROM inserted WHERE LocationCode=''MYS'''
DECLARE @ID int = 'SELECT ' + 'id' + ' FROM inserted WHERE LocationCode=''MYS'''

INSERT INTO  [#TempActivityEvents]
EXEC dbo.spLocationEvents
    @ID = @ID,
    @Date = @ActivityDate

END
GO

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @Karu3103 Please also share what the stored procedure `spLocationEvents` is doing. It is not efficient to loop through the `inserted` table inside the trigger and execute the stored procedure for each row. It is best to duplicate what the stored procedure is doing inside the trigger.

Comment: It is a very lengthy procedure, and in all cases there would be only one record that gets inserted into the base table for a given date and for a particular ID. So was thinking if it was easier to use the procedure instead of reusing the entire code all together?